# Add user agent with httpclient 4.0.1

Tags: java, jenkins

I need to add a user agent with the library httpclient 4.0.1

```
    HttpClientParams httpparams= new HttpClientParams();
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(httpparams);
    string userAgent = "my user agent";
    if (userAgent != null && userAgent.length() != 0) {
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
    }
```

i get this error message:

**error:**

cannot find symbol httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);

**symbol:**

variable CoreProtocolPNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;